# A more elegant way to extract individual bits from hex bytes object in Python?

Tags: python

I have this working code, but it looks to me way too complicated ref what it really does.

Basically I want to create a hex word based on extracted specific bits from a bytes object (the string is a VISCA PTZ string). In this example the required result is in form of 0x00 (or its decimal equivalent, this is not important), but can be also as 0x0000 if more bits are involved.

```
aa = b'\x80\x01\x04\x48\x00\xff'
# extract these --^---^

bb = b""
cc = 0
    for i in range(0, len(aa), 1):
    partial = aa[i:i+1]
    if i == 2:
        j = [partial[0] & b'\x0f'[0]]
        cc = cc << 4 | j[0]
    elif i == 3:
        j = [partial[0] & b'\x0f'[0]]
        cc = cc << 4 | j[0]
    bb = bb + partial

print (cc)      # gives 72 = 48 hex (which is the intended result)
```

Perhaps later I need also to change some bits and put it back to the bytes string (no code yet for this).

I played a bit by reading directly the members of the original bytes string, but I messed up with conflicts between different object types.

Is there a more simple and elegant way to do it ? (Python 3.5 here)

Comment: Why is `j` a list? Can't it be an integer? Also, you can use hex literals: `b'\x0f'[0] == 0x0f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aa = b'\x80\x01\x04\x48\x00\xff'

part1, part2 = aa[2] & 0xf, aa[3] & 0xf
print(hex(part1 << 4 | part2))
```

For more parts the expression will be more complicated, but still simpler than what you did.